# DotNet new no funciona despues de desinstalar una plantilla personalizada

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, angular8

Trabajando con netcore, tuve que instalar una plantilla personalizada. Posiblemente haya eliminado esa plantilla porque la utilice únicamente para para un caso puntual.

A día de hoy quise crear un proyecto desde la consola utilizando el comando **"dotnet new"**, y me encontre con un error que decia lo siguiente:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Desktop\dotnet-template-samples\01-basic-template'.
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.CreateDirectoryHandle(String path, Boolean ignoreNotFound)
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.Init()
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1..ctor(String directory, Boolean isNormalized, EnumerationOptions options)
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1..ctor(String directory, FindTransform transform, EnumerationOptions options, Boolean isNormalized)
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerableFactory.UserEntries(String directory, String expression, EnumerationOptions options)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalEnumeratePaths(String path, String searchPattern, SearchTarget searchTarget, EnumerationOptions options)
   at System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Utils.PhysicalFileSystem.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(String directoryName, String pattern, SearchOption searchOption)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.Scanner.DetermineDirectoriesToScan(String baseDir)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.Scanner.Scan(String baseDir, Boolean allowDevInstall)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.TemplateCache.Scan(String installDir, IReadOnlyList`1& mountPointIdsForNewInstalls, Boolean allowDevInstall)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.SettingsLoader.RebuildCacheFromSettingsIfNotCurrent(Boolean forceRebuild)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.New3Command.ExecuteAsync()
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.CommandParsing.NewCommandInputCli.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<<OnExecute>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

El comando dotnet new quedo totalmente inutilizado.

Intente reinstalando el SDK de netcore 3.1 que es la versión que tenia instalada y no funcionó.

Quise instalar nuevamente la plantilla pero al tener que hacerlo a través del comando "dotnet new" no fue posible hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gente, acabo de encontrar la solucion a este problema en la pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59773338.

Muchas gracias!